# Application class can be used for store data? (persistent data)

Tags: persistence, android

I'm trying to use Android `Application` class (MyApplication.java) for store data in some `ArrayList`s of strings and `int`s

I want that these data get's stored forever, like a database, **but without using databases**, to simplify my app.

Currently the data get's stored when I exit of the app only when the process of the app is still on background. But if i kill the process of the app, the data stored on MyApplication.java class get's removed.

There is a way to solve this?

Code resumed:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static String LeagueTable[][] = new String[21][8];
    //COLUMNAS MATRIZ:
    //0     /1   /2   /3   /4   /5   /6   /7
    //nombre/P.J./P.G./P.E./P.P./G.F./G.C./Pts

    public static League LFP = new League();
    public static Category Primera = new Category(20);
    public static int NEQUIPOS=20;
    public static int[][] matriz= new int[NEQUIPOS+1][NEQUIPOS+1]; //esta es la matriz de emparejamientos, representa el calendario
    public static int PlayerTeamID;
    public static boolean ExistingSaveGame=false;//esto es true cuando existe una partida guardada

    //variables candidatas a poner dentro de una de las clases del modelo, como season por ejemplo
    public static int RoundNumber; //jornada actual
    public static boolean SeasonOver=false;//true cuando la temporada ha terminado

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

"and a lot of functions that works with the static variables"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can not.  If you don't store your data in storage (that doesn't need to be a db, could be a flat file or whatever) then it is not persistent.

Comment: there is a way to store in variables format?  (arraylist, array[][], etc.. ?????? i need to do it without databases

Comment: Take a look at [ObjectInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). Those will work as long as everything you are saving can be serialized.